# IS it posible to emulate firmware?

Tags: firmware, pcie, rom

Currently, i've been trying to work on virtualizing a motherboard from an old Lucent BZ5000 equipment, my idea is to emulate the BIOS from that equipment on a modern PC and be able to connect physically to the PC:

**-A Memory Controller Card:**

PCI card with a FPGA and some EPROM that technically works like an old USB where you load software.

**-A SCSI Card:**

The one that the system boots in, this is the one that searches for the Memory Controller Card.

**The BIOS is an Award 4.0 BIOS, and from what i've seen, Phoenix makes kinda the same BIOS now.**

I need to emulate the specific BIOS or another one with an SCSI boot option.

Downside is that electrical engineering is very different from the software engineering i learned, but i've done my best research to find my answer, the best i've done is running the BIOS of the board through a software that runs the ROM file like software, but not recognizing PCI ports and such, and finding QEMU, an emulator/virtualization tool that from what i found, is able to run firmware.

So is it posible to emulate Firmware, more specifically, a BIOS? cause searching through the web, i only find emulators for Video Game consoles BIOS and ROM files.

Thanks,

Diego Jarquin.

Comment: It would be very hard and would likely involve making some modifications to the BIOS (key areas) as well as writing emulator software that isn't easy to write. When I worked at Intel, we'd emulate the entire processor using a big huge cube of FPGAs and a tiny little "pod" that plugged directly into the motherboard. Breakpoints, too! (At the time, Intel owned half of Phoenix.) That would allow you to do emulation. But ... well... with enough time and money anything is possible. ;)

Comment: Lucent 20-years-old switches are highly proprietary. BIOS is usually highly tailored to particular hardware, it initializes a lot of internal specifics, including encryption of 50% of BIOS code. At the same time BIOS was never a plug-and-play system, and usually doesn't have much luxury to report errors. Therefore, as soon as the code will see some missing or unusual hardware (or software model of hardware, if done in simulator), it will simply hang. So your project is indeed very challenging.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? As you already know, QEMU runs BIOS just fine, so emulating a BIOS is indeed possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first questions comes to mind - why you want to do it? I am sure that equipment was superseded by the new equipment which you can use with much less effort.

> Is it possible to emulate firmware?

Firmware is a piece of software, very closely tied to the platform it manages, thus firmware can not be *emulated*, it can be *run*. To have it running properly, some hardware should be emulated. And this is what @jonk is taking about in the comment to your question.

There're generally two ways -

- making replica of hardware and make software/firmware run on it. In your case would it be simpler to find old motherboard which may have your memory and SCSI card installed, and connect the resulting PC device to your modern PC using network?
- making software emulator, which requires a lot of knowledge about the hardware you are going to emulate.

> i only find emulators for Video Game consoles BIOS and ROM files

Because those machines are relatively easy to emulate, and making this emulation has specific purpose - to entertain people with old good games.

In your case emulation is going to be very difficult, and, probably, pointless (you are to decide); as I said it may be easier to construct device using real old hardware and run it.